# How to Search only SUBURB list in Google Place API

Tags: android, arraylist

Is it possible to search within a SUBURB in Google places api? For example, can I force Places API to return only results from a particular 'locality' or country?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I force Places API to return only results from a particular 'locality' or country?

**Yes you can**  just use **[AutocompleteFilter.Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder)**

**Public Method Summary**

> **`setCountry(String country)`**
>   The country to restrict results to.
>
> **`setTypeFilter(int typeFilter)`**
>   Allows you to restrict the result set of a Place Autocomplete request.
>
> Allows you to restrict the result set of a Place Autocomplete request.

Valid values are:

- TYPE_FILTER_NONE
- TYPE_FILTER_GEOCODE
- TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS
- TYPE_FILTER_ESTABLISHMENT
- TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS
- TYPE_FILTER_CITIES

**sample code**

```
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
        .setCountry("AU")// set her your Country
        .build();

autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
// or 
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                            .setFilter(typeFilter)
                            .build(this);
```

for more information rtead from the **[Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete)**